# Conocer 2 valores menores de un array en función del sexo - Java

Tags: java, netbeans, array-bidimensional

tengo varias cuestiones por si me pueden ayudar:

Tengo los siguientes arrays:
`int[] arraySexo = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1};`
Donde el 0 es hombre y el 1 mujer.
`int[] arrayEdat = {15, 23, 41, 21, 54, 71, 31, 42};`
Edad de cada persona

Me gustaría saber 2 cosas:

1. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para modificar los números 0 y 1 de tal manera que me permita conocer el sexo literal de cada persona al recorrer el bucle for?

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < arraySexo.length; i++) {
              if (arraySexo[i] == 1) {
                 arraySexo[i]="mujer"; // Esto no es correcto, es un ejemplo de lo que me gustaría conseguir
               } else {
                 arraySexo[i]="hombre"; // Esto no es correcto, es un ejemplo de lo que me gustaría conseguir
               }
           }
   System.out.print("El número 0 equivale a hombres")
   System.out.print("El número 1 equivale a mujeres")
   ```

Es decir, si amplío mi código y pido más datos al usuario, que al imprimirlos me identifique el 0=hombre y el 1=mujer.

2. Saber la edad menor en función del sexo

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < arrayEdad.length; i++) {
               if (arrayMinuts[i] < menor) {
                   menor = arrayEdad[i];
   ```

Al hacer lo anterior, tan sólo consigo la menor edad en general, pero me gustaría que quedase algo así:

```
    System.out.prinln("La edad menor de la mujer es: 15 años")
    System.out.prinln("La edad menor del hombre es: 21 años")
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Comment: Hay una parte que no entiendo **si amplío mi código y pido más datos al usuario, que al imprimirlos me identifique el 0=hombre y el 1=mujer.** , Quieres almacenar en un nuevo array dependiendo si es 1/0 o solo quieres que imprima si es hombre o mujer dependiendo del valor 1/0, son 2 cosas diferentes.

Comment: Hola Joshin, si disculpa. Me refería a que cuando imprima el resultado, imprima si es hombre o mujer dependiendo del valor 1/0, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para tu consulta 1 no es necesario crear un nuevo arreglo porque solo quieres mostrar un mensaje dependiendo del valor que tenga tu arreglo `arregloSexo`.
El código sería

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySexo.length; i++) {
      if (arraySexo[i] == 1) {//mujer
            System.out.println("arraySexo ["+i+"] = Mujer");
       } else {//hombre
            System.out.println("arraySexo ["+i+"] = Hombre");
       }
}
```

Para tu consulta 2, primero necesitas recorrer `arregloSexo` para verificar si es hombre o mujer, luego comparar en `arregloEdad` si es menor que la variable que vamos inicializar con 999 años (nadie llega a esa edad en la actualidad, por ello inicializamos con esas edad); si el elemento i del `arregloEdad` es menor o igual a nuestra variable inicializada entonces actualizaremos el valor de nuestra variable declarada.

```
int menorMujer=999;
int menorHombre =999;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayEdad.length; i++) {
    if (arraySexo[i] ==0) {//si es hombre
        /*si la posición donde elemento de la posición i es menor 
        actualizamos el cambio de valor a menorHombre
        */
        if(menorHombre>=arrayEdad[i]){
            menorHombre=arrayEdad[i];
        }               
    }
    else{//si es mujer
        /*si la posición donde elemento de la posición i es menor 
         actualizamos el cambio de valor a menorMujer
        */
        if(menorHombre>=arrayEdad[i]){
            menorMujer=arrayEdad[i];
        }                
    }
} 
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("La edad menor de la mujer es: "+menorMujer+" años");
System.out.println("La edad menor del hombre es: "+menorHombre+" años");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Joshin, me ha sido muy útil. 
Quería aprovechar para preguntarte. Si quisiese hacer lo mismo para un array bidimensional, sería igual?
(En este caso, conocer el menor peso de cada sexo...
Teniendo: arraySexoEdadPeso={{1,15, 65},{0,23,75},{1,41,80},{0,21,110},{1,54,90},{0,71,98},{0,31,68},{1,42,75}}
Gracias

Comment: si es lo mismo, pero prefiero trabajarlo con una clase que tengas como atributos: sexo, edad, peso y guardar en un ArrayList de objetos

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, entendido.

Answer (score 0):

La primera parte es almacenar el resultado final en un array aparte

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySexo.length; i++) {
       if (arraySexo[i] == 1) {
          arrFinal[i]="mujer";
        } else {
          arrFinal[i]="hombre"; 
        }
    }
```